# Two linkTextAttribute with two different colour of UITextView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have taken a UITextView. In which i want to show two linkTextAttribute with two different colour. how is it possible?

suppose in my UITextView i have written - "My name is Abhishek Sinha"
i want to make Abhishek and Sinha two different link with two different colour.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728466/use-multiple-font-colors-in-a-single-label-swift

Comment: Yes, i did change the colour of attributed string but when i make it linkTextAttribute then colour of text changed with same colour.but i want to show link attribute with two different colour.how is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView linkTextAttributes font attribute not applied to NSAttributedString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053694/uitextview-linktextattributes-font-attribute-not-applied-to-nsattributedstring)

Comment: Abhishek Sinha, did you find the answer? I've been searching for the same thing for days now. If you did can you give me a hint?

Comment: Marian Petrisor, i did not find any answer till now.